# Using bash for loop variable within awk print

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to understand a specific situation within bash and awk:

I want to use the awk **binary operator** for *string concatenation between two variables* (a space) as the variable iterated,`$i`, within a bash for loop:

```sh
$ for i in ' '; do 
  echo "foo bar" | awk '{print $1$i$2}'
done
foofoo barbar
```

Expected output is: `foobar`

#### Question 1

- What is going on? [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35811639/2238178) (marked as correct)

#### Question 2

- How can I get awk to use string concatenation as in the above bash for loop? [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35811669/2238178)

#### Reference

```
$ $SHELL --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)

$ awk --version | head -n1
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.3, GNU MP 6.1.0)
```

Full test

```
$ for i in '+' '-' '*' '/' '%' ' ' ''; do echo "2.0 4.0" | awk '{print $1$i$2}'; done
2.02.0 4.04.0
2.02.0 4.04.0
2.02.0 4.04.0
2.02.0 4.04.0
2.02.0 4.04.0
2.02.0 4.04.0
2.02.0 4.04.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a little bit tricky one. Actually it prints `foo`, `foo bar` and `bar`. As the value of `i` is not defined in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (it is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variable) it is considered as `$0` (I did not know this behavior, but it make sense).

Change the code a little bit as

```
for i in ' '; do 
  echo "foo bar" | awk '{print $1"<"$i">"$2}'
done
```

Output:

```
foo<foo bar>bar
```

If you want to pass the value of the variable `i` you can do using `-v` argument. But `$i` will not work as the value of `i` should be a number in `$i`, so just use simple `i`.

```
for i in ' '; do
  echo "foo bar" | awk -v i="$i" '{print $1"<"i">"$2}'
done
```

Output:

```
foo< >bar
```

Comment: I tried `-v`, but it doesn't work, output of `for i in ' '; do  echo "foo bar" | awk -v i="$i" '{print $1"<"i">"$2}'; done` is `foo< >bar`, it should perform string concatenation so output is `foo<>bar`

Comment: I tried using my solution to `-v` and it still doesn't work `for i in ' '; do echo "foo bar" | awk -v i="$i" '{print $1"<"'i'">"$2}'; done` outputs `foo< >bar`

Comment: @adam if you do not want a space between `foo` and `bar` just do not pass the `$i` to [tag:awk]! Try `awk '{print $1$2}'`. The output is `foobar`. (But I do not understand the importance of `$i` then... ;) )

Comment: in my question: `I want to use the string operator to perform concatenation within a for loop:` Just an exercise for fun on bash/awk fundamentals :)

Comment: @adam What is the `the string operator` means? A concatenation in `awk` is to write the two variables close to each other. For positional parameters it can be done as `$1$2` for normal variables it can be done as `i j`.

Comment: I edited my answer and thought I could link directly to headers, but I don't think I can. Anyway, look at **Test** in my answer to see the operator in action.

Comment: @adam So if the expected output is `foobar` then the `$i` should not add. In this case use `$1$2`. If you want to also concatenate the environment variable `i` then you can use `awk -v i="$i"` and then `$1 i$2`. Of course you can directly use the environment variable using the `'"$i"'` but it is much harder to read and the resulting `awk` script is `print $1 $2`.

Comment: `i` is a regular shell variable, not an environment variable.

Comment: Adding to @chepner's comment: also, please don't call Awk's _field variables_ (`$1`, ...) _positional parameters_. You're confusing Awk and shell concepts. With `i` undefined, both GNU Awk and Mawk indeed interpret `$i` as `$0` (i.e., the entire input line), but BSD/OSX Awk actually _breaks_ with `awk: illegal field $(), name "i"`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the comment! What is the practical and/or theoretical difference?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as an environment variable. What is commonly called such is a shell variable whose value was initialized from the environment, which is just a list of strings of the form `name=value`. If `name` happens to be a valid shell identifier, a variable named `name` is created with the given value. Also, any shell variable `x` can have its export attribute set, which means the string `x=$x` (after expansion) will be added to the environment of any child processes.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the correction! And for testing on different `awk`s! IMHO OSX error is the better handling of this issue...

Comment: @TrueY You're welcome. Can I also suggest you separate the `print` arguments with spaces, so as to show how Awk string concatenation works differently from the shell? You _can_ do `$1$2`, but it's conceptually cleaner to do `$1 $2`, especially given that you can't do `xy` with non-field variables `x` and `y` (as you state): `{ print $1 "<" i ">" $2 }`

Comment: To complement @chepner's comment: Environment variables (name-value pairs) are part of the environment of _any_ process - they have nothing to do with the shell per se.
Shell variables are internal to a shell, and no other process sees them, unless they're explicitly also made available as environment variables via `export`.
However, the shell also conveniently exposes preexisting environment variables (e.g., `$PATH`). Thus, "non-exported environment variable" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the comments! The [tag:bash] variable become the called executable's environment variable (passed as char **env) if it is exported or entered just before the executable in the command line. So I think maybe my wording is not exact, but it is very understandable and not misleading. IMHO.

Comment: @TrueY: The wording is precisely the point: please use established terminology to avoid confusion. Calling `$i` an environment variable is simply incorrect (and qualifying it with "non exported" doesn't help).

Comment: The statement `it is a non exported bash environment variable` makes no sense since the term `environment variable` doesn't apply (`i` outside of awk is simply a shell variable and `$i` within awk is trying to access the field whose number is stored in the awk variable `i`) and the behavior within the awk script would be the same whether the shell variable `i` was exported or not. Your wording is misleading because, at least, it sounds like exporting the shell variable `i` would make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I tried making this a comment but there's just too much to say and some of it needs formatting:

@adam you seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding of awk that's making it hard for you to grasp what you're being told. I suspect it comes down to this - **awk is not shell**. Awk is a completely separate tool/language with it's own scope, variables, functions, etc.

Do NOT try to access the value of shell variables directly within an awk script by using intermediate single quotes (e.g. `awk '{print $1'"$i"'$2}'`) because that will turn the value of the shell variable into part of the awk code before the interpreter reads it and open you up to horrendous errors with cryptic error messages (or worse - insidious bugs with no error messages) given various values of `$i`.

You say you `Cannot get -v to work even without for loop:` but then you show it working perfectly twice:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk -v var=" " '{print $1var$2}'
foo bar
```

In the above case you create an awk variable named `var` that contains one blank character `" "`. Then you print $1 (`foo`) followed by var (`" "`) followed by $2 (`bar`) and the output is `<foo>< ><bar>` exactly as it should be.

In all of your examples you are setting a variable to a single space character, concatenating that with some other values (e.g. `-v var=" "` then `$1var$2`) and then for some reason expecting that space character to not be present in the output.

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk -v var=" " '{print $1'var'$2}'
foo bar
```

In the above case you create an awk variable named `var` that contains one blank character `" "`. When you write any shell script (awk, sed, grep, whatever) that's enclosed in single quotes:

```
any_cmd 'abc'
```

then you are telling `cmd` to interpret/execute what's inside the sign quotes. You **cannot** include single quotes in a single quote delimited script - that's shell fundamentals. So when you write:

```
any_cmd 'abc'def'ghi'
```

the inner single quotes are actually breaking out of the `any_cmd` language and back to shell to interpret and the shell attempts to it expand it before `any_cmd` is called. So if you have:

```
xyz=17
any_cmd 'abc'$xyz'ghi'
```

then what `any_cmd` actually sees to interpret is:

```
any_cmd 'abc17ghi'
```

but if you have something in there that the shell can't expand then it gets left as-is so:

```
and_cmd 'abc'def'ghi'
```

gets passed to `any_cmd` as:

```
any_cmd 'abcdefghi'
```

So back to your example:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk -v var=" " '{print $1'var'$2}'
foo bar
```

The `var` between $1 and $2 will be interpreted by the shell first since the `'`s around it are taking it out of the awk script and back to shell, but then it's just some text that shell can't expand so the above is passed to awk as-is which makes it:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk -v var=" " '{print $1var$2}'
```

and in a roundabout way you got back to your first script and again the output is as expected.

The above sounds complicated but it's actually extremely simple:

To concatenate strings in awk, just put them side by side.

To pass the value of a shell variable to awk, use `-v`, e.g. `awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'print "foo" awkvar "bar"'`.

Rather than trying to learn awk by trial and error, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins first and then play with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to compose that. I should have clarified in my post, in the `Explore: -v` section, I did not expect `-v` to work. I was just showing the output due to someone else saying it would work. When you say `Do NOT try to access the value of shell variables directly within an awk script by using intermediate single quotes...` that was actually my question! How can I expand the variable before awk interprets it :)  `i` wouldn't be arbitrary, it would be restricted to the values as listed in the **Test** section: `'+' '-' '*' '/' '%' ' '`

Comment: I should have used integers or floats in all my examples rather than the string `foo bar`. I think that is confusing people in misleading to think that I was trying to do a general string concatenation. That was stupid of me.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a warning about using it for general string concatenation. Also I updated the example for using `-v`, this may be more clear what I'm trying to do. `echo "2.0 4.0" | awk -v var="+" '{print $1var$2}'` output is `2.0+4.0`, desired output is `6`. Is it possible using `-v var="+"`? More clear?

Comment: Yes it's more clear, no it's not possible, why would you want to do that? It's like if you had a C program tst.c that contained a line `2.0 var 4.0` in it and planned to run it every time as `sed 's/var/+/' tst.c > tmp.c && gcc tmp.c` using whatever op you want instead of `+`. Yeah you can physically make it work but I doubt if you'd win any awards for C or shell programming by doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured out **Question 2**.

Initial for loop:

```
$ for i in ' '; do echo "foo bar" | awk '{print $1$i$2}'; done
foofoo barbar
```

#### Explore: quoting

Enclose `$i` in `"`:
`'{print $1$i$2}'` to
`'{print $1"$i"$2}'`

```
$ for i in ' '; do echo "foo bar" | awk '{print $1"$i"$2}'; done
foo$ibar
```

#### Solution: quoting

Which led me to trying to break up awk with `'` so `$i` can be correctly evaluated:
`'{print $1"$i"$2}'` to
`'{print $1'"$i"'$2}'`

```
$ for i in ' '; do echo "foo bar" | awk '{print $1'"$i"'$2}'; done
foobar
```

#### Test solution

Using solution to test all awk binary operators and null:

```
$ for i in '+' '-' '*' '/' '%' ' ' ''; do 
    echo "2.0 4.0" | awk '{print "Using binary operator \"'"$i"'\" for \""$1"\" and \""$2"\" evaluates to:\t" $1'"$i"'$2}'; 
  done
Using binary operator "+" for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:     6
Using binary operator "-" for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:     -2
Using binary operator "*" for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:     8
Using binary operator "/" for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:     0.5
Using binary operator "%" for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:     2
Using binary operator " " for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:     2.04.0
Using binary operator "" for "2.0" and "4.0" evaluates to:      2.04.0
```

Note: `''` is not a binary operator obviously and is just a check.

Success!

Warning: as pointed out by others, this solution is **not for general string concatenation**. The shell variable `i` should only be awk binary operators. Setting `i` to any other variable will probably cause issues.

#### Explore: `-v`

Using `-v` does not appear to allow binary operation:

```
$ echo "2.0 4.0" | awk -v var="+" '{print $1var$2}'
2.0+4.0
```

Output: `2.0+4.0`
Desired output: `6`

Comment: Note that the shell requires you to use `$` to get the value of a variable. awk does not (it's like C in that regard). In awk `$` is like an *operator* to get the value of the **field** given by the variable: `echo a b c | awk '{print $2; x=2; print x; print $x}'` will output `b`, `2`, `b`

Comment: You want `awk -v var=":" '{print $1 var $2}'`

Comment: @glennjackman I understand `$<number>` is used to reference the current record, delimited according to the variable `NS`. Obviously if I just wanted a solution I would do `echo "foo bar" | awk -v var="" '{print $1'var'$2}'` to get output as `foobar`, or just not use `-v` at all. Also, I do not want a separator as your suggestion provides, `:`. What I'm trying to do is have the binary operator trigger via `<space>` to concatenate two variables. I should be able to iterate over all binary operators as shown in **Test** sect. If you have a solution to do this using `-v` I would love to hear it :)

Comment: As has been mentioned elsewhere, to concatenate two strings, you want `awk '{print $1 $2}'`

Comment: Sorry, it's probably my fault. :( I should have used integers in all my examples rather than the string `foo bar` I think that is confusing a lot of people. I want to either pass via variable any of the binary operators (e.g. `+`, `<space>` , `*`, etc) into the print command between the two vars. I solved it with for loop, but I don't think it is possible with `-v` in a for loop. Thanks anyway for your help.