# Print specific rows of a column using awk in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

Can anyone help with a similar issue? I intend to print specific rows of a column using awk in for loop. I used similar codes as suggested here but could not get any output. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811546/using-bash-for-loop-variable-within-awk-print) but I just did not get any output. I cannot figure it out.

```
    # my input file: sfs_file.new.txt
    57 6546 492 3844 1685 4234 2959 6586 5810 4187
    63 6658 525 3955 1637 4356 3039 6562 5878 4086
    65 6523 495 3978 1663 4310 2960 6515 5708 4235
    71 6522 507 3915 1597 4282 2948 6719 5746 4172
    58 6593 518 3965 1690 4213 2940 6527 5697 4144
    # expected result:
    65
    71
    58
    # My codes as below
    for i in {3..5};do
        awk -F " " -v var=$i 'FNR==var {ptint $1}' sfs_file.new.txt
    done
```

Comment: change `ptint` to `print`

Comment: to print rows from 3 to 5 without forloop `awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=5 {print $1}' file`

Comment: Aha, thank you @ufopilot so much for pointing the error out. I should have been more careful.

Comment: You do not need provide space as field separator, as this is GNU `AWK` default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other alternatives...

```
$ sed -n '3,5s/ .*//p' file
```

or

```
$ awk 'NR==3,NR==5{print $1}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@ufopilot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4177828/ufopilot) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506833/print-specific-rows-of-a-column-using-awk-in-for-loop/77507049?noredirect=1#comment136640249_77506833) you have `ptint` instead of `print`. Awk takes that as an unpopulated variable name, concatenates it with `$1`, and then does nothing with the result, hence no output.

No need for a shell loop, though:

```
$ awk 'NR==3{f=1} f{print $1} NR==5{exit}' file
65
71
58
```

We exit when NR is 5 for efficiency, no point reading the rest of the file and doing nothing with it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it showed nothing. That's what I wondered why I did not get any error messages. I actually want to use awk-for-loop as a basic step to replace a pattern in a specific line from another file with the variable of each row in a specific column.

Comment: why not `awk 'NR>=3{print $1} NR==5{exit}' file` without using `f`

Comment: @ufopilot that'd be fine too, I'm just used to using flags for jobs like this and I started out writing `'NR==3{f=1} f{print $1} NR==5{f=0}'` before realizing the `exit` would be more efficient so just changed `f=0` to `exit` without putting any more thought into it.

Comment: Real data are with the last col separated by "\t" so requiring -F "\t". 
Sorry in the ex data I did not present it in the example data for test.
## real data: sfs_file.new1.txt
`5 6 3 1 42 29 66 10 47 ft_sim_1_1_MSFS.obs`

Comment: Tabs instead of blanks separators would make no difference to the question you asked. Also, please don't try to add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed - make sure everything we need to know to help you is clearly shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the real data are a bit more complex than the previously posted example data. Real data are with the last col separated by `"\t"` as below so requiring `-F "\t"` I think.

```
## real data: sfs_file.new1.txt
5 6 3 1 42 29 66 10 47  ft_sim_1_1_MSFS.obs
```

My final intention is to use this awk-for-loop as below.

```
for i in {1,4..5};do
    ## replace pop AA,CC,DD -> filename in col2
    sfs1=`awk -F "\t" -v var=$i 'FNR==var {print $2}' sfs_file.new1.txt`
    sed -i -e "3s/AA/$sfs1/" -e "12s/CC/$sfs1/" -e "20s/DD/$sfs1/" ft_sim_MSFS_1_"$i"_MSFS.blueprint
    ## replace pop BB -> filename in col1
    sfs2=`awk -F "\t" -v var=$i 'FNR==var {print $1}' sfs_file.new1.txt`
    sed -i "7s/BB/$sfs2/" ft_sim_MSFS_1_"$i"_MSFS.blueprint
done
```

Comment: Don't do that - it contains multiple bugs and anti-patterns, is fragile, inefficient, and non-portable. Edit your question to better explain your problem and provide adequate sample input/output if existing answers don't do what you really need.

Comment: Actually what that script is doing looks very different from what you asked for in your question so you should just [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to the question you asked and then ask a new question about what you really want to do.